# DatePicker postback return original value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a calendar like this:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77PK8.png)

**Controller:**

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

 fecha_fin.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-MX");

 }


  protected void DateChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fecha_fin.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
        }
```

**View:**

```
  <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="fecha_fin" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="DateChange" DayNameFormat="FirstLetter" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="11px" NextMonthText="." PrevMonthText="." SelectMonthText="»" SelectWeekText="›" CssClass="myCalendar" CellPadding="0">
                    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#b0b0b0" />
                    <DayStyle CssClass="myCalendarDay" ForeColor="#2d3338" />
                    <DayHeaderStyle CssClass="myCalendarDayHeader" ForeColor="#2d3338" />
                    <SelectedDayStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12px" CssClass="myCalendarSelector" />
                    <TodayDayStyle CssClass="myCalendarToday" />
                    <SelectorStyle CssClass="myCalendarSelector" />
                    <NextPrevStyle CssClass="myCalendarNextPrev" />
                    <TitleStyle CssClass="myCalendarTitle" />
                </asp:Calendar>

            </td>
```

For default it have today date picked, problem start when I pick another day, it change date correctly with "DateChange" method, problem starts when I pick some other thing in my page, it return post today date again

For example [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dshZ.png) here I have 31-October selected but text return 12-December again. Why page reload postback as original one (when page load)? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        fecha_fin.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-MX");
    }

}
```

On page load Check if its not page load .. This will not change values on post back ...

if (!IsPostBack) <-- This checks if its post back call or page refresh call..